# LEFT JOIN - Return empty results with left join for sum of payment_method

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

This is my first question on stackoverflow so I try my best to not screw up. I am scratching my head on this query for a couple of hours and can't make any progress.

I use a view which has several bookings in it. All those bookings have a payment_method e.g. paypal or creditcard.

```
Customer Name | Price | payment_method
John Doe      |  20   |  creditcard
Susan Soe     |  10   |  paypal
```

With my sql query I am trying to get the sums for all payment_methods. Unfortunately payment_methods which were not used this month don't show up.

So I created an additional table called PaymentMethods with the column Methods.

```
Methods
creditcard
premium
sofort
bank
paypal
```

I then tried to use a `LEFT JOIN` to get a result like this:

```
payment_method  | TotalQuantity (->sum(price))
creditcard      | 20
premium         | 0
sofort          | 0
bank            | 0
paypal          | 10
```

But instead I only get those sums returned which have a payment_method used that month already.

```
payment_method  | TotalQuantity (-> sum(price))
creditcard      | 20
paypal          | 10
```

This is my statement. I would really appreciate some input on what I do wrong here.

```
SELECT payment_method, SUM(IFNULL(price,0)) AS TotalQuantity 
FROM PaymentMethods 
LEFT JOIN PaymentMethods
ON SlotBookingsFullView.payment_method=PaymentMethods.Methods
WHERE (booking_date BETWEEN '2018-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-07-30 23:59:59')
```

*** EDIT ***
m0lochwalker pointed out that I should use `GROUP BY` clause...I had it but it got during copy&paste action. Here it is.

```
GROUP BY PaymentMethods.Methods ORDER BY PaymentMethods.Methods DESC
```

Comment: Your result is what a LEFT JOIN would do. You should SUM TotalQuantity and Group By payment_method. Have you looked at the Group By clause? Something like:

Comment: There is one more typo in your query: `FROM PaymentMethods LEFT JOIN PaymentMethods` must be `FROM PaymentMethods LEFT JOIN SlotBookingsFullView` of course.

Answer (score 2):

When you outer join records, their values are null:

```
PaymentMethods.Methods  | B.payment_method  | B.booking_date   | B.Quantity
------------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------
creditcard              | creditcard        | 2018-07-01       | 2
creditcard              | creditcard        | 2018-07-05       | 1
creditcard              | creditcard        | 2018-04-21       | 4
premium                 | NULL              | NULL             | NULL
...
```

So with

```
WHERE (SlotBookingsFullView.booking_date BETWEEN '2018-07-01 00:00:00'
                                             AND '2018-07-30 23:59:59')
```

you are dismissing all outer-joined rows, because their `booking_date` is not in the desired date range, but null obviously. This renders your join a mere inner join. Put criteria on outer-joins in their `ON` clause instead:

```
SELECT pm.Methods, COALESCE(SUM(b.Price), 0) AS TotalQuantity 
FROM PaymentMethods pm
LEFT JOIN SlotBookingsFullView b
  ON  b.payment_method = pm.Methods
  AND b.booking_date >= date '2018-07-01'
  AND b.booking_date <  date '2018-07-31' 
GROUP BY pm.Methods
ORDER BY pm.Methods DESC;
```

(As you see, `COALESCE` or `IFNULL` belongs outside of `SUM` not inside it, because if the *sum* is null, you want to replace it with zero.)

Comment: Your solution is working just perfect! Also thank you for the explanation Thorsten!

Answer (score 0):

Your result is what a LEFT JOIN would do. You should SUM TotalQuantity and Group By payment_method. Have you looked at the Group By clause? Something like:

```
SELECT payment_method, sum(totalquantity) as qty
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY payment_method
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right. GROUP BY is needed and I had it already but  lost it when copying it over. See edit. 
What I don't understand in your reply is how sum(totalqantity) should work. totalquantity is not a column but a 'variable'.

Comment: I was on mobile and reading fast. Thought I could help by suggesting Group By. Glad you got it working.

Comment: By the way you could have grouped by your ‘variable’ without creating another table by using CTE. Check them out.